# Excel 2010 is quick to calculate but slow to start up

Tags: performance, excel, startup

I have created an excel database that takes information from a number of sheets and stores the data in a single 'database' sheet in a layout that makes it easy to create a pivot table to capture all of the data in the database. The information in the database tab is all either linked directly to cells in other sheets or using the offset function to link to cells in other sheets.

The database page is just over 10,000 rows and just over 100 columns (i.e. about a million linked cells). I have been trying to find solutions to this problem, but have been unable to do so. Calculation time is relatively quick as the workbook does not make use of array formulas such as sumifs or sumproduct.

Is the database just too big or is there a way to avoid the extremely slow start up (20-30 minutes)?

Thanks!

Comment: 30 minutes? You definitely need to convert your Excel data into database, something like SQLite or MS Access. Any database driven app should start in less than 1 second, and compute quickly especially if you have indexes set up.

Comment: (1) This isn't that big. I suspect your file is linked to other files and it is relinking on start-up? (2) Use PowerPivot if you have xl2010 or xl2013, you don't need to go to an external option such as Access.

Comment: It's only internal links. Is it somehow possible to cut this out during start up as in document calculations are not problem.